# Adding new objects in a list, all the objects look like the last one

Tags: python

I'm making my first program in Python. I need to add objects to a list, and I create these objects inside a FOR loop. The problem is, after filling the list, if I check the value of any object, they all look like the last object added.

```
class clsNumeros:

    numero = 4
    oper = [int() for i in range(5)]

    def __init__(self, op1, op2, op3, op4):
        self.oper[1] = op1
        self.oper[2] = op2
        self.oper[3] = op3
        self.oper[4] = op4

    def CountOperaciones():
        return 5

    def GetValorOper(self, idxOper):
        num = self.oper[idxOper]

        if num == 1:
            return num
        elif num == 2:
            return sqrt(num)
        elif num == 3:
            return Factorial(num)
        elif num == 4:
            return 4/10
        elif num == 5:
            return sqrt(0.4)

    def GetExprOper(self, idxOper):
        num = self.oper[idxOper]

        if num == 1:
            return num
        elif num == 2:
            return "R(" + num + ")"
        elif num == 3:
            return num + "!"
        elif num == 4:
            return "0.4"
        elif num == 5:
            return "R(0.4)"

    def Display(self):

        txt = ""

        for x in range(1, 5):
            txt = txt + str(self.oper[x])
            txt = txt + " ___ "

        print (txt)



def GeneraNumeros():
    c = []
    idx = [int() for i in range(5)]
    i = 0
    idx[1] = 1
    idx[2] = 1
    idx[3] = 1
    idx[4] = 1
    looping = 1
    n = 0

    while looping == 1:
        num = clsNumeros(idx[1], idx[2], idx[3], idx[4])
        c.append(num)
        n = n + 1
        idx[4] = idx[4] + 1
        for i in range (4, 1, -1):
            if idx[i] > clsNumeros.CountOperaciones():
                idx[i] = 1
            idx[i-1] = idx[i-1] + 1
        if idx[1] > clsNumeros.CountOperaciones():
            looping = 0

        c[5].Display()  # this is for displaying object number 5. All of them look like the last one

    return numeros
```

What could be wrong? Can I create objects inside a FOR loop and expect them to be unique?
This idea works fine on ASP.NET.

Thanks!

Comment: plz fix the indentation of your code first ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
class clsNumeros:

    oper = [int() for i in range(5)]
```

class variables are evaluated once, at the moment of class definition. Therefore, only one instance of list is created here. Fix that by initialising `oper` in the constructor instead.

Other issues:

- you can just say `0` instead of `int()`
- you can just say `[0]*5` instead of `[0 for i in range(5)]`
- naming conventions: Python uses `method_name` and `ClassName`, it's good to follow them
- get the habit of writing `class clsNumeros(object)`, because the other (older) syntax results in an "old-style" class in Python which behaves a bit differently
- you can simplify the method `Display` by using the `str.join` method, for example `'__'.join(items)`

Comment: Thanks!! Now I understand. Sorry if it looks like a duplicated question, but I though my problem was different. Now I see that class variables should be declared inside the __init__ part.

Comment: *Instance* variables should go into `__init__`, while class variables go directly inside the class definition. Also note that for simple immutable objects (numbers, strings) it doesn't make such a big difference: `obj.numero` will access the class variable initially, but `obj.numero += 1` will write into the instance and this one will be picked up next time.